# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, input, amazon-s3, outputstream

I use the code below to get image:

```
public Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(String urlStr) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlStr).openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos);
        copy(bis, bos);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baos.toByteArray(), 0, baos.size());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm sure of the permisson and wifi connection.
 such as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: are you able to browse same image from browser?permission to write in external storage?

Comment: @praveen Yes, I can browse the same image and have downloaded before. But sometimes the exception will come out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error then might be there is 2 issue.

1) Either you forget to add permission of internet in android manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2) If you are running in real device then your device is not connected with internet. Check whether your device is connected with internet or not.

Comment: I'm sorry. Neither is right. I just use the emulator and do add the permission. The exception came out for a few times.

Comment: @anna, whenever you get exception check whether internet is there or not, because i had a same issue few weeks backs and after long time i came to know that my device was not coonected with wifi.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I use the AVD, and 100% sure of the network that has been connected with wifi.

Comment: After I close the AVD and start the AVD again, the downloading is OK. But, but, but, the exception will come out now and then. Do you think it's the memory problem?

Comment: If it is memory problem then you will get `outofmemory` or other error. I don't think that is issue.